# "Quantifier follows nothing in regex" replacing + and =

Tags: regex, perl

I have written this line to replace `+` and `=` with space. But it returns an error stating

> Quantifier follows nothing in regex

```
$element= ~ s/+/ /g;
$element= ~ s/=/ /g;
```

Is this correct? How do I combine both conditions in one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+` has a special meaning in regexes: it's a quantifier meaning "1 or more". To use `+` literally, backslash it.

```
$element =~ s/\+/ /g;
```

But, if you want to replace both `+` and `=`, you can add them to a character class, where `+` loses its special meaning:

```
$element =~ s/[+=]/ /g;
```

Note that `tr` is faster.

```
$element =~ tr/+=/ /;
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. It works :) Can you also let me know how do I write an array to any file.  Will Print FILEPOINTER(@ArrayName) will work?

Comment: To ask a new question, ask a new question. "Thank you" - upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: Or, using `tr///`, you can write `$element =~ tr/+=/ /`